# Alert if munin-master contact node

Tags: monitoring, munin

I have installed **munin** on one of my servers, and **munin-node** on another server I wish to monitor. I would like an alert if for any reason the node can't be contacted by the master. Is it possible to configure munin to do something like that, either the way I have stated above, or through plugins?

Or is munin really not designed to do this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Munin is not designed to do this at all.  It may, however, be possible by patching the Munin source code.  (Source:  http://grokbase.com/t/sf/munin-users/092qk1vxpk/how-to-trigger-a-notification-when-a-node-cant-be-contacted)